# Doctrine - Can I use real SQL (not DQL) in a ->andWhere()?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

I'm using Doctrine, a PHP ORM. I have created a Doctrine Query, and I need more control. So I've started to use the `->andWhere(...)` methods to add new where clauses. However I need to do a subquery based on another table, like so:

```
$query->andWhere("id in (SELECT id from other_table where value = ?)", $myvar);
```

The above doesn't work. However there is no Doctrine class for other_table, and doctrine keeps trying to load the file `other_file.php`. I have figured out that it is interpreting this as DQL (right?). Is there someway I can tell Doctrine to not interpret this as DQL, so that I can just use raw SQL?

I know I could use `Doctrine_RawSql`, but that would involve rewriting all of this query. It would be nice if there was a halfway house.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately with Doctrine 1.x it is not possible to do this, even using RawSql.

All RawSql queries require that every table selected be mapped to a 'Component', which is really a Doctrine_Record class.

You might be better served adding a class for that other table, even if it's stupidly simple and never used anywhere else.

Otherwise, you'll have to drop to raw PDO using:

```
$dbh = Doctrine_Manager::connection()->getDbh();
```

See [Doctrine_RawSql](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/native-sql)

Comment: Thanks for the info.I like the general idea of Doctrine and other orm, but its performance hit always concerns me.

Comment: @jspcal: Thanks, I thought you had it out for me :P

Answer (score 2):

Even if being able to do this kind of thing *(i.e. usings DB tables that are not mapped to a Doctrine class, and using pure-raw-SQL)*, I don't think it's possible with Doctrine 1.x

Maybe with Doctrine 2.0 -- which is announced for the end of this year... Which is not soon ^^